# How to run ant build.xml (having UI selenium Test cases) from Jmeter to see performance?

Tags: ant, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, build.xml

I have my ant build.xml to run all my UI test cases. Now my task is to check the performance report so I am looking to integrate it with JMeter. How I can achieve this. Can anyone please share steps or link to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough hardware power (CPU, RAM, etc.) you can consider using [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

If you want to use JMeter the best option would be converting your UI-based Selenium tests into [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol based JMeter tests, this way the footprint of the tests will be much lower.

For example looking into [Firefox 73.0.1 System Requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/73.0.1/system-requirements/) it looks like you need to have 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM for single browser instance while with JMeter you should be able to simulate at least a hundred of virtual users with this CPU and RAM.

With regards to conversion options:

1. You can record them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) by [configuring your Selenium tests to use JMeter as the proxy](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/faq/selenium-testing-proxy/).
2. You can use [Proxy2JMX Converter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/#Proxy2JMX-Converter) module of the [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool to do the conversion for you, check out [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/) article for more details.